# How to get absolute path in qml with Android

Tags: android, image, path, qml, qt5

I am trying to get path of image in qml with Android.

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: "Android QML App"

    Image {
        id: name
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: "file:////storage/emulated/0/background.png"
    }
}
```

It didn't work. I I have tried a lot (storage, Internal shared storage,...) but it still not work.

Comment: For the latest generation Androids, access to storage cards is restricted. See https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage for more information.